# CoreData files attribute meaning A vs M vs Nothing

Tags: xcode

When I created NSManagedOjectSubclass, XCode creates between two files for me, with attribute of "A" on the far left. What does A mean? I have seen other files with attribute of "M", and some files with no attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Those characters refer to the source control status of the file (they do not have anything to do with Core Data). More [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html).

```
M = Locally modified

U = Updated in repository

A = Locally added

D = Locally deleted

I = Ignored

R = Replaced in the repository

– = The contents of the folder have mixed status; display the contents to see individual status

? = Not under source control
```

Comment: It might be nice to identify these as statuses from a source control system to make it clear it's nothing specific to Core Data.

Comment: Providing a brief summary before the status codes would be helpful.